# Use condition with map

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

```
canBeTransferred$ = this.userService
.getCurrentUser()
.pipe(map((user) => user.data.id === this.ticket.userId || user.data.isCsm || user.data.owner));
```

I have a observable like above and I want to add another condition

```
this.ticket.status !== 'Archived'
```

I am trying like

```
canBeTransferred$ = this.userService
.getCurrentUser()
.pipe(map((user) => user.data.id === this.ticket.userId || user.data.isCsm || user.data.owner) && this.ticket.status !== 'Archived');
```

but the compiler is throwing error. How to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you put on the wrong place the new condition, it should be like:

```
canBeTransferred$ = this.userService
.getCurrentUser()
.pipe(map((user) => user.data.id === (this.ticket.userId || user.data.isCsm || 
user.data.owner) && this.ticket.status !== 'Archived'));
```

Just enclose in parentesis all the existing conditions and add another one next to the closing parentesis.

```
user.data.id === (this.ticket.userId || user.data.isCsm || 
user.data.owner) && this.ticket.status !== 'Archived'
```

Comment: canBeTransferred$ = this.userService.getCurrentUser().pipe(
    filter(() => this.ticket.status !== 'Archived'),
    map((user) => user.data.id === this.ticket.userId || user.data.isCsm || user.data.owner),
  );

Comment: This this look like a good way?

Comment: Looks like a good solution also, did it works to you?

Comment: @lerihard_v, yours worked as well and mine too :D. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help you.